# What causes a series of \pscurve paths in \pscustom to produce unexpected result?

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to fill some custom area in pstricks, and I am a bit surprised by the outcome. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.3)(3,3)
\psclip[linestyle=none]{%   
\pscustom{
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
  }}
  \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.6](-3,-3)(3,3)
\endpsclip
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.3)(3,3)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]{
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
  }
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.3)(3,3)
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the outcome:

[image]

The shape I want to fill is shown on the right. On the left and in the middle the outcomes of two different attempts to fill the shape are shown. Not only that both do not precisely fill the shape, also the mismatches depend on whether I use `\psclip` of the directly `\pscustom`. Why is that?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Thanks! (I'm wondering if you want to post an answer, others may have the same problem.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `\pscustom`  the *last* point of a line/curve (path) is *always* the *first*  point of the following curve (path)! For example:

```
      \pscustom{%
        \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
        \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
        ...
```

is wrong!  The second `\pscurve` has now four (!) pairs of coordinates:

```
        \pscurve(2.5,-2)(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
```

and that is far different to a curve with `\pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)`
Delete the first point and all will be fine!

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.3)(3,3)
\psclip[linestyle=none]{%   
    \pscustom{
        \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
        \pscurve(0.9,0)(0,2)
        \pscurve(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
    }}
    \psframe*[linecolor=gray,opacity=0.6](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \endpsclip
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
    \end{pspicture}

    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.3)(3,3)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]{
        \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
        \pscurve(0.9,0)(0,2)
        \pscurve(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
    }
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
    \end{pspicture}

    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.3)(3,3)
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no difference in the following two curves:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.3)(3,3)
\pscustom[linewidth=4pt,linecolor=blue]{
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
    \closepath
}
\psset{linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt}
    \pscurve(-2.5,-2)(0,-1.5)(2.5,-2)
    \pscurve(2.5,-2)(0.9,0)(0,2)
    \pscurve(0,2)(-0.9,0)(-2.5,-2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But why is the outcome for my above curves different depending on whether or not I use `\psclip`? Naively, I'd expect this to be the same since these should now be the same curves (even if they are wrong).

Comment: Well, I understand this. But from your answer I get that the boundary curves have now 4 points. But shouldn't they still be unique?

Comment: @marmot: It has nothing to do with `\psclip`. The only difference is using `\pscustom` or not using it.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity: A `liftpen` setting in a series of curves without a moveto makes no sense!

Comment: Sorry, probably I'm stupid, but how come that the contours that `\pscustom` produces are different then?

Comment: @marmot: see edited answer

Comment: `liftpen` is for curves which are _not_ continuous. In this example there is no "hole" in the complete figure, so no `liftpen` needed.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Would you mind writing an answer elaborating the many comments you've left in this thread? I'm sure it would be highly educational and appreciated.

Comment: Well, I looked at your updated answer (and am very grateful that you spent so much time in writing it). But I still don't understand what's going on, i.e. why the left and middle figures in my question are different. Of course, I tried to add `\closepath` here and there, but this did not make the figures equal.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I am comparing the contours of the shaded areas in the left and middle figures of my post. And I can't help believing that these contours are caused by `\pscustom` since in both cases the only weird shapes are in `\pscustom`. I just want to know what's going on. (BTW, I'd love to accept both answers, but this forum does not allow this. Both answers are really great, even though they leave some questions open, they allow me to get the picture I want.)